# Reformatting a date-frame into a new output format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a the output from a pivot table in dataframe (df) which is that looks like:

```
  Year Month             sum
  2005    10    -1.596817e+05
          11    -2.521054e+05
          12     5.981900e+05
  2006     1     8.686413e+05
           2     1.673673e+06
           3     1.218341e+06
           4     4.131970e+05
           5     1.090499e+05
           6     1.495985e+06
           7     1.736795e+06
           8     1.155071e+05
                     ...
           9     7.847369e+05
           10   -5.564139e+04
           11   -7.435682e+05
           12    1.073361e+05
  2017      1    3.427652e+05
            2    3.574432e+05
            3    5.026018e+04
```

Is there a way to reformat the dataframe so the output to console would look like:

```
Month     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
Year
2005
2006
2007
2008
2009
2010
2011
2012
2013
2014
2015
2016
2017
```

All the values would be populated in the new table as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `unstack`:

```
In [18]: df['sum'].unstack('Month')
Out[18]:
Month         1          2           3         4         5          6          7         8         9          10        11        12
Year
2005.0       NaN        NaN         NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN -159681.70 -252105.4  598190.0
2006.0  868641.3  1673673.0  1218341.00  413197.0  109049.9  1495985.0  1736795.0  115507.1  784736.9  -55641.39 -743568.2  107336.1
2017.0  342765.2   357443.2    50260.18       NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `df.pivot(index='year', columns='month', values='sum')`.

To fill you empty (if empty) year column use `df.fillna(method='ffill')` before the above.

Reading the answer above it should be mentioned that my suggestion works in cases where year and month aren't the index.